# Some sites show illegible numbers after Catalina upgrade

Tags: macos, font, catalina, text, web-browser

After upgrading to Catalina I noticed that some sites were showing this weird text.  It looks like the site is showing characters that are not supported by the font, but this is not just one site, it is on several sites and they are sites that I have been to and had regular english text before the upgrade.

How do I revert them to normal ?

> [image: hotchpotch fonts]

Comment: google chrome in that screenshot

Comment: Please try Safari and Firefox and state in your question whether all browsers behave the same.

Comment: Go to Font Book.app and do File > Restore Standard Fonts and restart.

Comment: Also give us some example site

Comment: well I did the Restore Standard Fonts thing in Font Book and so far I am not seeing any illegible text.  I will repost as soon as I see it again, but it is looking like that fixed the issue.

Comment: Tom's answer must have worked because I have not seen the text since that time.  If you write an answer I'll mark it as the solution, otherwise just thanks